control next version when turbo repo installs it
When I try to create a turbo monorepo I get Next 15 and React 19 (and their dependencies)
pnpm dlx create-turbo@latest

Ant Design is not compatible with the latest React. So, I want to force turbo to install next 14 instead (and other dependencies accordingly).
I tried using a flag to downgrade repo:
pnpm dlx create-turbo --turbo-version 1.13.3

So this downgrades and inside repo folder I get the 1.13.3 version. But Next and React version are not affected at all.

Maybe this issue could help you https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/51458
